# Sobolev norm on Lawson's Spin Geometry book

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

[image]

This is from Lawson's book "Spin Geometry", if $u$ is a $\mathbb{C}^p$-vector function $$u=(u_{1},...,u_{p}),$$
what norm take when use in (2.7) $$|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2$$
Thanks

Comment: hmm this is interesting.  I would think the standard norm on $\mathbf{C}^p$ but I am not completely sure.

Comment: and the standarn norm in $\mathbb{C}^p$ how is

Comment: $\mathbf{C}^p$ is an an inner product space

Comment: can you tell me what is $\left \langle u, v \right \rangle$ in formula $(2.6)$. is product intern in $\mathbb{C}^p$